# Изменение столбца MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

**Приветствую всех**, есть проблема, которую не могу решить.
Итак, есть таблица [image: таблица]
нужно изменить значение столбца(оно сейчас пустое) **'msg'** , не меняя значение столбца room_id, но в ту же строку, таблица называется rooms. Пробовал так **INSERT INTO rooms SET msg='hey' WHERE room_id='1234';** и еще несколькими способами, но никак. Буду признателен за помощь в решении.

Comment: Не INSERT INTO, а UPDATE. Почитайте учебники по SQL

Comment: Благодарю, точно, запамятовал.